# Exploding a string ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following which is returned from an api call:

```xml
<WORST>0</WORST>
<AVERAGE>93</AVERAGE>
<START>1</START>
```

I need to parse this to just give me the `<AVERAGE></AVERAGE>` number, 93.

Here's what I'm trying but get error detected:

```vb
res = AjaxGet(url)
myArray = split(res,"AVERAGE>")
myArray2 = split(myArray[1],"</AVERAGE>")
response.write myArray2[0]
```

I'm brand new to ASP, normally code in PHP

Comment: VBScript arrays don't use square brackets `[]` for starters. For example `myArray[1]` should be `myArray(1)`. What is `AjaxGet(url)`?

Comment: That's all it was, if you want to answer I'll accept, many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript doesn't recognise square brackets `[]` when accessing Array elements and will produce a `Syntax Error` in the VBScript Engine.

Try making the following changes to the code snippet to fix this problem;

```vb
res = AjaxGet(url)
myArray = split(res,"AVERAGE>")
myArray2 = split(myArray(1),"</AVERAGE>")
response.write myArray2(0)
```

---

> **On a side Note:**
>
> Parsing XML data in this way is really inefficient if the `AjaxGet()` function returns an XML response you could use the XML DOM / XPath to locate the Node and access the value.